# SQL: How to replace only trailing strings?

Tags: sql, replace

I need to replace only trailing strings in SQL DB. The DB currently has this:

```
Sony Co
Coca Cola
Coke
Sony Company
```

We need to remove " Co" from the Sony line

So output looks like this:

```
Sony
Coca Cola
Coke
Sony Company
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: What database?  SQL Server, MySQL, etc?

Comment: trailing strings? Will the trailing stirng always be " Co", Why isn't Cola a trailing string?

Comment: @BS123 I'd just like to replace the trailing string.. not the middle of the string

Comment: Is it always going to be " Co"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
select (case when name like '% CO' then left(name, len(name) - 3)
             else name
        end) as newname
```

Note:  you don't specify the database.  In some databases, `len()` is `length()`, and you would use `substr()` or `substring()` instead of `left()`.

Comment: Apologies, it's SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE urtablename
SET name = replace(name , 'Co', '') Where name like N'%Co'